# Trying to Redirect Subdomain URL to Subdirectory Index

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Subdomain:

> live.mysite.com

Subdirectory file to point to:

> /my-admin/src/index.html

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#If the host is "sub.domain.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live.mysite.com$ [NC]
#Then rewrite any request to /folder
RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /my-admin/src/$1 [NC,L]
```

Results in an internal 500 error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming your htaccess is ok, try changing permissions of the file with chmod. I.e chmod 444 .htacess

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona I'm on cPanel but I changed the permissions to 0444, still the same error

Comment: If you change last line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-admin/src/$1 [NC,L]` error still exists?

Comment: Same error unfortunately @JarekBaran